# SQLite: Group records with nearest integer field

Tags: sql, sqlite

There is a table with integer field. I need to write a query which returns groups with the following condition: min value of the field in the some group differs more than N to max value in the next group.

Example with N=10.

SQL query for the table

```
01    A    A    1
02    A    B    9
03    B    B    11
04    B    C    22
05    C    C    29
```

should return

```
01    A    A    1    0
02    A    B    9    0
03    B    B    11   0
04    B    C    22   1
05    C    C    29   1
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10016802/python-group-a-list-of-integer-with-nearest-values) is a similar question for Python. How to do this in SQLite?

Comment: What's the grouping field, your second `CHAR(1)` column?

Comment: Grouping field is the last field with integers: 1, 9, 11, 22, 29.

Comment: I thought that was the fields you were trying to get the differences from?  How do I know what group those numbers belong to?  Or are you just trying to figure out a running 'difference' among the numbers?  What is the criteria for group start/end?