# How to group a list of tuples by nearest values for the n-th element?

Tags: python-3.x, list, group-by, tuples

I have a list of tuples which looks like this:

```
d = [(1,1,1),
     (2,1,1),
     (1,2,1),
     (1,12,1),
     (13,50,4),
     (1,13,32),
     (4,48,100),
     (0,121,5)
]
```

And group this list by nearest values for the first element of each tuple, like this:

```
d_ordered = [
     [(1,1,1),(2,1,1),(1,2,1)],
     [(1,12,1),(1,13,32)],
     [(4,48,100),(13,50,4)],
     [(0,121,5)]
]
```

I found this:https://stackoverflow.com/a/10017017/9071615
which does it for a simple list. I tried to use that as a base but have no idea how to extend the solution to a list of tuples.

Any idea how to have the most efficient sorting for list of tuples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import  groupby
n = 1
a = np.array([i[n] for i in d])# or np.array(d)[:,n] if all the elements of d have the same shape
b,c=np.where(np.abs(a-a[:,None]) < 5)# I used a maximum distance of 5, you did not specify exactly the allowable distance
e=set(tuple(k[1] for k in j) for i,j in groupby(zip(b,c),key=lambda x:x[0]))
[[d[j] for j in i] for i in e]

[[(1, 1, 1), (2, 1, 1), (1, 2, 1)],
 [(0, 121, 5)],
 [(13, 50, 4), (4, 48, 100)],
 [(1, 12, 1), (1, 13, 32)]]
```

Comment: That exactly did the trick! Although, understanding what is happening at 'e'is difficult I am happy to find out. Furthermore, I will noodle around and see if other solutions would be more efficient or not. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Kishintai at `e`, first I `zip(b,c)`. you can do `list(zip(b,c))` to see the results. Then I group c using b. Now this will be repeated. I take a set of it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using `sorted()` and `lambda`:

```
d = [(1,1,1),
     (2,1,1),
     (1,2,1),
     (1,12,1),
     (13,50,4),
     (1,13,32),
     (4,48,100),
     (0,121,5)
]

d_ordered = sorted(d, key = lambda x: (x[1]))

print(d_ordered)
```

Output:

```
[(1, 1, 1), (2, 1, 1), (1, 2, 1), (1, 12, 1), (1, 13, 32), (4, 48, 100), (13, 50, 4), (0, 121, 5)]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Alas, this doesn't group by nearest values but by absolute values...